# Beautifulsoup filter by contain a class and not another class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to filter the script that contain the 'class' and NOT include 'style', and I do not want to use set, because it does not return the proper answer.
here`s the script:

```
<p class="price hidden-xs" style="width:100%">-</p>
```

and I using this code:

```
milage = soup.find_all('p', {'class' : 'price hidden-xs'})
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply filter out elements that have a `style` attribute with a conditional list comprehension:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

markup = (
    '<p id="with_style" class="price hidden-xs" style="width:100%">-</p>'
    '<p id="without_style" class="price hidden-xs">-</p>'
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")

print(
    [
        e
        for e in soup.find_all("p", {"class": "price hidden-xs"})
        if not e.has_attr("style")
    ]
)
```

Result:

```
[<p class="price hidden-xs" id="without_style">-</p>]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
milage = soup.find_all('p', {'class' : 'price hidden-xs', 'style' : False})
```

This should give you all `p` tags with `class = price hidden-xs`, and none with the `style` attr.

↳ [BS : The basic find method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs))

Answer (score 1):

you can use `fromstring` and specify not style attribute in an xpath expression

```
#import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring
# url = ''
# tree = html.fromstring( requests.get(url).content)
h = '''
 <p class="price hidden-xs" style="width:100%">Not me</p>
 <p class="price hidden-xs">Me</p>
'''
tree = fromstring(h)
items = [item.text for item in tree.xpath("//p[@class='price hidden-xs' and not(@style)]")]
print(items)
```